# Wildcard prerequisites gives strange error message

Tags: makefile

In this example:

Makefile:

```
eat_pie: pie
    rm pie

eat_%: %
    rm $*
```

Terminal:

```
$ make eat_pie
make: *** No rule to make target `pie', needed by `eat_pie'.  Stop.

$ make eat_cake
make: *** No rule to make target `eat_cake'.  Stop.
```

Why doesn't make eat_cake output that the target cake is missing?

The GNU Make manual states:

> Wildcard expansion is performed by make automatically in targets and
>   in prerequisites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite unclear what you're asking. Wildcard substitution works in given example (unless targets are declared as phony - wildcards are not expanded for phony). Your problem is that your 'eat_' rules depends on file's existance. You don't have 'pie' or 'cake' files, and make don't know how to build them (because there is no rules to do so), that's what error message says.

Comment: I am expecting a more specific error in the wildcarded target, namely that there is no rule to make target cake. But instead make is telling me that it doesn't even have a rule for eat_cake. Which is strange, since eat_% clearly matches eat_cake.

Comment: Nothing strange. This is exact reason why wildcards don't work for phonies - there is no file to match it against. If you will create file 'cake', it will match. This is how make wildcards work - matching against existing files.